# ¿Qué es lo que se "trae" cuando algo "se las trae"?

Tags: etimología, modismos

Comencemos con una cita del CORDE:

> *Y la autoridad, o séase Mariano Marzo, que ya por el camino, y a la vista de la pizpireta novia apetitosa, había ido echándose sus cuentas, así que en la mejor alcoba de los Mochos instaló a la que se hallaba bajo el fuero de la galantísima justicia, llevó al corral al alguacil (cuya mujer corría con las prostitutas que solían traer de Badajoz, por semanas, para sus juergas, los señoritos del Curdin), y le habló de esta manera:*
>
> *—Mira, Colás, la nena se las trae. Ya has visto qué frescura y qué modo de reír. La he dado un sobón, y no ha chistado. Por otra parte, simple, me preguntaba en la fonda si irá su novio a presidio. Voy a ver de acostarme con ella esta noche, a poco que se deje.*
>
> Felipe Trigo, "Jarrapellejos", 1914 (España).

El otro día me di cuenta de que "se las trae" es una de esas frases hechas que decimos sin pensar en su significado literal. Según el diccionario:

> **[traérselas](http://dle.rae.es/?id=aE26oeU#BclJtq5)**
>
> 1. loc. verb. coloq. Dicho de una persona o de una cosa: Tener más intención, malicia o dificultades de lo que a primera vista parece.

La expresión no debe de ser demasiado antigua. El primer caso que veo en el CORDE es de 1895, y de 1893 en la hemeroteca de la BNE. Más atrás los casos son literales, como ocurre con el siguiente ejemplo:

> *En cambio, le voy cobrando un cariñazo enorme a Bobita, mi perra. Es una delicia... Ningún chico hace más gracias. La verdad es que me lo destroza todo, que no me deja cosa sana, que mis zapatillas se las trae arrastrando al taller y mis calzoncillos lo propio [...].*
>
> Emilia Pardo Bazán, "La Quimera", 1905 (España).

Sin embargo, de algún sitio tuvo que salir la expresión. Si nos atenemos a su significado literal, ¿cuál es el origen de la misma? ¿Qué es lo que se "trae" cuando algo "se las trae"?

Comment: Sólo se me ocurre que tenga relación con *traer(se) (algo) entre manos*.

Answer (score 1):

Lo más que he podido encontrar sobre el origen de la expresión es [este texto](http://hemerotecadigital.bne.es/issue.vm?id=0030310069&page=2&search=%22se%20las%20trae%22&lang=es), encontrado en la hemeroteca de la BNE, que data de 1891:

> A los juegos de palabras únense ahora los *modismos*, los *timos*, los *camelos*, los giros extraños, tomados unas veces de idiomas extranjeros, recogidos otras entre la *chulapería* madrileña é inventados no pocas en los llamados círculos de buen tono<sup>1</sup>.
>       Hoy se oye decir:
>       "Fulano *se las trae* para un rato."
>       O bien:
>       "Eso es muy fin de siglo;" ó «¡Qué fin de siglo es Mengano!"
>       En verdad os digo que el que oye uno de esos *timos* por vez primera, no sabe si trata con dementes ó con *graciosos*: reconocer esto último cuesta muchísimo trabajo.
>
> <sub>1: Propios de gente distinguida o elegante.</sub>
>
> La Justicia (Madrid). 8/11/1891, página 2.

Nótese como el texto pone en cursiva *se las trae*, indicando que esa expresión es la que contiene el *timo* ("dicho o frase que se repite a manera de muletilla") o el *camelo* ("dicho o discurso intencionadamente desprovisto de sentido" o "chasco, burla"). Es decir, que esa frase muy posiblemente carezca de sentido. Nótese además que lo de "para [un rato](http://dle.rae.es/?id=VEKIuUF#5zNOEAH)" puede significar "mucho" (aunque por aquella época se usaba "un buen rato", según el DLE de entonces).

Por tanto, podemos centrar su origen en la última década del siglo XIX, posiblemente fruto de la *chulapería* madrileña, aunque sin poder especificar qué se trae porque seguramente ni en su origen se quisiera que significara que se trajera nada en concreto, especialmente si su origen era burlesco como parece ser.